# seaborn clustermap row reorder

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I am trying to re-order a seaborn clustermap using the row order of a former clustermap, in this way:

```
p = sns.clustermap(m1, cmap='RdBu_r', linewidths=0.5)
order = p.dendrogram_row.reordered_ind
ind = m2.index[order]
m2 = m2.reindex(ind)
sns.clustermap(m2, cmap='RdBu_r', linewidths=0.5)
```

The m2 is sorted correctly when I print it but when I put it in the clustermap the heatmap is not sorted, could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think clustermap is plotted according to a clustering, regardless what order you pass in. It may be a solution to create a custom distance matrix and then pass it as a linkage. If you got your cluster labels from a previous clustering then just simply create a distance matrix, where the distance is zero if two items are in the same cluster.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd

# create some random 3 dimensional data
data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10), columns=["x", "y", "z"], 
data=np.random.random(size=(10,3)))

# create some random clustering with 3 different labels
cl_labels = [0,1,2]
cluster_labels = np.random.choice(cl_labels, size=data.shape[0])
prepared_clustering = pd.Series(index=data.index, data=cluster_labels)

# create a "distance" matrix
# distance for items in the same cluster will be zero, distance to elements outside the cluster are arbitrary (non-zero)
d = np.array([cluster_labels]*10)
distance_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=data.index, columns=data.index, data = (d != d.T)).astype(int)

# create some colors to illustrate the clustering
colors = dict(zip(cl_labels, sns.hls_palette(len(cl_labels), l=0.5, s=0.8)))
row_colors = prepared_clustering.map(colors)

# plotting the clustermap
sns.clustermap(data,
           col_cluster=False,
           # don't turn off row_clustering, because it will do some default clustering/ordering
           row_cluster=True,
           # set the row_linkage to a custom linkage generated from the distance matrix
           # have no clue, but without the ssd.squareform a warning is displayed. the result is the same anyway
           #row_linkage=linkage(distance_matrix),
           row_linkage=linkage(ssd.squareform(distance_matrix)),
           # decorate with the rows
           row_colors=row_colors
          )
```

[Clustermap with predefined clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxA1.png)